# Getting a numerical literal type value in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I wanted to model my domain more clearly with types instead of using magic numbers, but the following code doesn't seem to work the way I'm expecting to. Is there a correct way to do this using types or should I resort to Enums?

```
type Down = -1;
type Up = 1;
type Direction = Up | Down

const go = (pos: number, dir: Direction): number => {
  if (dir instanceof Up) {
    console.log("going up");
  }

  if (dir === Down) {
    console.log("going down");
  }

  return pos + Up;
};

console.log(go(Up))
```

Gives me

`'Up' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

`The left-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any', an object type or a type parameter.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `enums` in this case.

```js
enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down = -1,
}

const go = (pos: number, dir: Direction): number => {
  if (dir === Direction.Up) {
    console.log("going up");
  } else if (dir === Direction.Down) {
    console.log("going down");
  }

  return pos + Direction.Up;
};
```

Comment: TypeScript `enum` are terrible and this usage in particular is absolutely terrible. By default, TypeScript assigns incremental numeric values to `enum` keys. In this case, `Direction` will end up having values `Up = 1`, `Down = -1`, yes, but if we were to add `Left` and `Right` below `Down`, then these values would respectively become `Left = 0` and `Right = 1`, clashing with `Up`. Prefer just using objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use types where a value is expected. Types are erased during compilation, so at runtime there is nothing to add or compare to.

You could use an enum, but you can also use literal types, by starting with the values and deriving the types from them:

```
const Direction = {
  Up: 1,
  Down: -1
} as const
type Direction = typeof Direction[keyof typeof Direction]

const go = (pos: number, dir: Direction): number => {
  if (dir == Direction.Up) {
    console.log("going up");
  }

  if (dir == Direction.Down) {
    console.log("going down");
  }

  return pos + Direction.Up;
};

console.log(go(0, Direction.Up))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgSwE4FNhQeGBeGBvAWACgYYBVABwC4YBGAGmNLhAHcwaBaW4gXxgCGEGKEhRiUAJ4UU8ZGgxZcUmSABmc1OkxgA2gGsUk9TBUoTiLYrABdYsVHQYAcxA4YACgogINMAFcAWwAjFCR6GAATZBpLBR0ASj8g0KQcAD58JhgEDQ9otOxcOO1wADpKBKySUhFwCBAAGxQyxpBnDwAiVwQwZxh-Ck6EgG5s3nsa3M8CnGL5UrAylnYqwhrSRyaWto7ukF7+yLYwYbGaiaJs1Ch-JDAYb2EAak148spz3nOHeu3W9oeVweAAMERK1gqFASCSAA)

Answer (score 1):

Not making use of the literal type system built into Typescript is losing out. You were *almost* there. Just replace `type` with `const` in your first two lines:

```
const Down = -1;
const Up = 1;
type Direction = Up | Down
```

If you did not need to refer to the constants in your code, you could make this even more compact and readable by inlining the `Direction` type into your function declaration:

```
const go = (pos: number, dir: -1|1): number => {
```

Have a look at the [official docs on literal types].(https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).